# What is a cheap device for measuring low-power IoT devices?

Tags: low-power, power-measurement

what are some cheap (around 50 USD) devices for measuring and logging the power consumption for low-power devices (like IoT, for example)?

Comment: Suggested : I use INA226 for such measurements and Bluetooth or Wifi transmission and it is working very well. Changing the "measuring resistor", I have scale below 1uA resolution.

Comment: I can, with this board, "measure" (estimated) the time life of a given battery ...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Andreas Spiess just did [a video](https://youtu.be/LUB8RWzzLWc) comparing various products to do just that.

His conclusion was that the [Nordic Power Profiler Kit II](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/Power-Profiler-Kit-2) was the best value option for most applications.